# How to Bake HighLight into BaseColor in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to bake Light info in One Texture for optimize in Unity.such as reflect,shadow,diffuse light, specular light.

I baked all in maya.
but i want to bake it in Unity.

I want some solutions in Unity.Don't want to bake it outside, then import Unity

Comment: -> e.g. [How to build Lightmaps in Unity 2020.1 | Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJ4fl-KBDR8) probably pretty similar now